# Is there a way to easily find dead dwellers in the vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My 200 person vault recently reduced to 198 because I didn't notice the two corpses stinking up one of my Hydroponic rooms. I didn't notice a happiness dip, I have too many rooms to notice that small a drop in productivity (all my dwellers have 10 in the appropriate stat), and I'm fairly certain the fatal incident took place while I wasn't playing. Is there a quick and easy way to find corpses short of visually inspecting each room or running down my entire dweller list every day?

(Related but not really relevant, I just had the fun of spending 10 mins trying to find the dead Mr Handy on my top floor; I finally found him just behind the front platform in my 3 wide super reactor.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Yes!

Dead dwellers have some interesting properties. Most importantly, dead dwellers have a status of "DEAD" and a happiness of 0%. We can sort on either of these values to quickly find the dead dwellers.

Open the dweller list by tapping the gear icon in the top left corner of the screen with the number of dwellers on it. Tap the smile face column to sort by happiness and scroll to the very bottom for the 0 happiness dead bodies.

[image: dead dwellers have low happiness]

You can click on the corpse's name and it should select the dweller wherever they are in the vault (or show them if they were exploring the wasteland).

You can tap the top of the status column in the dweller list to sort by status. This seems like it should work, but it sorts by room instead. (Thanks for pointing this out, [Ross Ridge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/86571/ross-ridge)!)

I'll leave this here in the hopes that Bethesda eventually fixes this bug.

[image: dead dwellers should have top status]

Comment: Sorting by status never worked for me. It just sorts by job and so dead people end up scattered through out the list.

Comment: @RossRidge hmm, I'll need to test that out. Let me kill some dwellers in different jobs and see what happens

Comment: @RossRidge you were right. I've update my answer to reflect that